# trying to calculate counter messages by distance

Tags: javascript, counter

I'm trying to display two messages:
1. One day before the event
2. On the event day
The message for the date after the event is working fine.
I tried to add  "distance = 1" and it seems to be the problem...

```
var countDownDate = new Date("<? echo $mounthname; ?> <? echo $d[2]; ?>, <? echo $d[0]; ?> <? echo $hourresp; ?>:00").getTime();
var x = setInterval(function() {
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  var distance = countDownDate - now;
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = " <? echo $line_within; ?> " + days + " <? echo $line_days; ?> ";
  if (distance === 1) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "<? echo $line_eventistomorrow; ?>";
  }
  if (distance === 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "<? echo $line_eventistoday; ?>";
  }
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "<? echo $line_eventisover; ?>";
  }
}, 400);
```

Comment: `=` is for assignment, `==` and `===` are for comparison.

Comment: Equality (==) The equality operator converts the operands if they are not of the same type, then applies strict comparison. If both operands are objects, then JavaScript compares internal references which are equal when operands refer to the same object in memory , So `if (distance == 1) {}`

Comment: I tried both "==" and "===", but still not woking...

Comment: Only change the `=` inside `if` statements to `===`

Comment: still not working...

Comment: Did you compare the timezones of both dates (`now` and `countDownDate`)? Sometimes JS uses different ones and so the `distance` may not become what you expect.

Comment: That's not how it works, @OlafWatteroth. Date objects are by default displayed in the user's local time, but they don't have an inherent timezone.

Answer (score 1):

You're checking `distance` when you mean to be checking `days`.

(Also note that `Math.floor` will give you an off-by-one error here; you want `Math.ceil`.  And that this sort of math won't really give you readings of "tomorrow" and "yesterday", instead you're getting "24 hours from now" and "24 hours ago".  For true date comparisons I'd suggest something like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) which simplifies much of this.)

```js
var countDownDate = new Date("December 1, 2017").getTime();
var now = new Date().getTime();
var distance = countDownDate - now;
console.log(distance); // this will not be 1 unless the countdown date is one millisecond in the future
var days = Math.ceil(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
console.log(days); // this is what you want
if (days === 1) {
  // ...
} // etc
```

Comment: Too obvious... this should be the answer.

Comment: but how can you add the exact time? like this: "December 1, 2017 19:30:00" It's not working for me...

Comment: What isn't working?  Can you be more specific please?

Comment: @DigiNetEvents If you mean that using that time currently returns 2 instead of 1 that's because of what I said above: you're calculating "24-hour intervals from right now", not "days starting at midnight".

Comment: Yes i want to calculate 24-hour intervals from now to the exact date and time from "countDownDate"

Comment: Dates start at midnight. 24 hour intervals start at whatever time it happens to be right now. You have to pick one or the other. If you want intervals use the code above. If you want dates use momentjs or similar.